# Script that only works if the server ip it is on whitelist

Tags: shell-script

Basically i want to create a sh script that only can be executed
if the server ip where the script it is being executed is present in
a private whitelist.txt file that is located in a different server.

Anybody can help me with a code example?

Thanks for your time ;)

---

i dont know how to make grep comparations / checks between the ip where the script is being executed and the whitelist allowed ips. Thats the part that becomes confusing for me.

Comment: So you want unauthenticated access to the whitelist, followed by IP matching? Any computer can manually set its own IP, so that won't work. Read `man -k ssh;man -k sshd` for a better way. OR you could use DHCP, with strict MAC to IP matching, and an empty public range

Comment: I want that only allowed ips (whitelist.txt file with allowed external ips hosted in my webhost) can execute my sh script.

Comment: when the script it is executed on linux, it will check if that server ip is present in a whitelist (whitelist.txt file uploaded to my webhost), if the ip it is included, then the script continues his work, if the ip is not included in my whitelist file, then the script will close.

Comment: Not even in principle. If you send me your script to execute, I could fetch the list myself, add a whitlisted IP to one of my NICs OR pull the script into an editor and "fix" the IP check. Research "software licensing".

Comment: Thats not the problem. What i want is to know how to create this kind of ip check.

Comment: If you wish to proceed, even after I explained that your method can easily be fooled, read `man curl wget` to see how to fetch the whitelist, and `man ip ip-address` to get the server's IP addresses. OR, set up a simple whitelist server that returns YES or NO.

Comment: Can you please give any usage example of this commands? I'm new with scripts. I already lost several hours searching for a way with wget and curl and i cant find it. thanks for your time..

Comment: Since you responded within 3 minutes, it looks like you have not read the `man` pages I suggested, and considered how they apply to your desires. If you're not going to follow suggestions, why should I make suggestions? What you want to do sounds silly, not worth the effort, and I don't code for free.

Comment: "What you want to do sounds silly" you're still insisting on this.  You can simply "encrypt" sh files. Most part of the users dont know how to decrypt it. So i want to do it anyway. I'm completely new. i do not even understand about "programming", thats why i'm asking you a simple example.  I see several threads in this forum and users basically answer with the entire code solution. so thats why i've created a thread, so somebody can give me a "code" example (cause even with manuals it is difficult for me).

Comment: Regarding your most recent comment:  This question is not simple. It involves two parts: 1) a script that queries a web service and reacts on the response (this is easy), and 2) a web service that responds in one way to a request from a certain set of IPs, and in another way to request from other IPs (this is less easy, especially if you want to do it safely, including setting up a public web service). It's not a question that you respond to with a simple one-liner, or even a short script.  We are not a code-writing service. Questions, especially non-trivial ones, need to show prior effort.

Comment: You can edit your question and add details. I did that for you based on your comment. Comments are not guaranteed to stick around (someone else may have the same problem, and search this site), so please always edit your question for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

This site is not a scriptwriting service, but here are some ideas. It's up to you to actually write the script.

1. Get current ip address: `ip addr | grep inet`.

This will usually give you several addresses, including IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, so you need to be more specific, and modify according to your needs.

2. Get whitelist from other server: E.g. run a HTTP server and get it via `curl` or `wget`. Or put it on a shared network drive. Or copy it via `scp`, assuming correct credential setup so nobody can do harm with those credentials.
3. Find IP in whitelist: Again use `grep`. **Edit**: You can use the [exit code of grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730043/the-exit-status-code-for-the-grep-command) to determine if a match happened, or not. See `man grep` for details, and `man bash` how to use it. Example:

   ```
   $ echo 'example' > whitelist.txt
   $ grep example whitelist.txt ; echo $?
   example
   0
   $ grep wrong whitelist.txt ; echo $?
   1
   ```

---

Note that this approach is completely unsafe: The whitelist will be publicly visible, and anybody can easily modify the script.

This approach is only usable if this script is only executed by trusted persons, and all you want to do is to prevent it from accidentally running somewhere where it shouldn't run.

There are also vastly superior methods to identify the current host compared to the IP address, e.g. the hostname (which you should be able to set if you manage the hosts where the script should run. And in any other situation you really shouldn't use the above approach).

Comment: Why should the web service give out the whitelist? Is the list public? Would it not be enough if the web service checked the IP of the client against a private whitelist and responded with the appropriate authentication HTTP response? The IP of the client is readily available to the service. The client could then act on the response code.  In any case, the script could be easily modified to avoid any attempt at authentication, unless later operations rely on some key fetched from the web service. This is not a simple task to get right.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers.  Answering:  1. "Get current ip address": i know i can simply use "curl ifconfig.me" (external ip address) | 2. "Get whitelist from other server": i have the whitelist.txt file (with all the allowed external ips) in my webhost. I can use curl one more time to read this file. | 3. "Find IP in whitelist": the thing is, i dont know how to make grep comparations / checks between the ip where the script is being executed and the whitelist allowed ips.  Thats the part that becomes confusing for me.

Comment: @taspior "_Get current ip address: i know i can simply use `curl ifconfig.me` (external ip address)_" - No! That will get the external address, which may not even exist for some systems. And on others it will be the NAT public address of every machine on an internal LAN. Please read the suggestions: `ip addr` is one valid way to get the machine's IP addresses